# Can't install Homebrew on MacBook Pro, password field won't input

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

I need to install Homebrew. I am unable to input the password when prompted in the Terminal - nothing happens when I type, only when I hit enter. I follow the instructions specified in the book I'm reading (Byte of Python). First, I enter:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

I get:

```
Press ENTER to continue or any other key to abort tests
MacBook-Pro:.ssh kevinadler$ organization21
bash: organization21: command not found tests
MacBook-Pro:.ssh kevinadler$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
==> This script will install: /usr/local/bin/brew /usr/local/Library/... /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
==> The following directories will be made group writable: /usr/local/. /usr/local/bin
==> The following directories will have their group set to admin: /usr/local/. /usr/local/bin
Press ENTER to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/. /usr/local/bin
WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.
To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.
Password: Sorry, try again. Password:
```

Any ideas how to enable me to enter my password?

Comment: Are you actually typing your password when prompted? The terminal will not show any characters for a password entry (not even masked) but they actually are being entered. Type the password and then `return`.

Comment: Are you entering a line at a time or pasting a whole lot at once. I assume organization21 is your password and this should not be entered until after the sudo which will prompt you for it

Comment: Also you don't need Homebre to install python - a version is included in the Apple supplied install

Answer (score 3):

Correct. The password does not show up its appearance, but you just type it correctly anyway, and then it'll bring you to the next "Intallation successful". Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing to not show any characters for the input, but your solution @juanli did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/344881)